# Make the main window scroll horizontally

Tags: css, html

I have the following css in a website. What im trying to do is make the secondDiv grow as much as it like and make the main window scroll horizontally, to push the window to the right and not start second div on a new line. SecondDiv should start to the left of first div and make the window scroll horizontally when x repeatingDiv fills the secondDiv.

Does anyone have any idea of how to accomplish this?

Help will be greatly appreciated!

```
<div class="firstDiv"></div>

<div class="secondDiv">

<div class="repeatingDiv"></div>
<div class="repeatingDiv"></div>
<div class="repeatingDiv"></div>
<div class="repeatingDiv"></div>

</div>
```

UPDATE:
Thanks James, it works, but now the first div that has much lesser height end up on the bottom of the page. Is there a way to keep the first div at the top no matther how high the second is?

Answer (score 1):

Make your div `display: inline-block;` 
add to there parent `white-space: nowrap;`
 than both div will always be on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this could work:

```
body{
    white-space: nowrap;
}

div{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

You won't need the width and height on the divs assuming they contain actual content.

http://jsfiddle.net/aYspk/

Comment: We arrived to the same answer, but you provided an example. 1 upvote for you my friend!

Comment: Thanks James, it works, but now the first div that has much lesser height end up on the bottom of the page. Is there a way to keep the first div at the top no matther how high the second is?

Comment: `vertical-align: top` on the `div`s.

Comment: Thanks! You know your css :)

Answer (score 0):

Use table display. Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5fvGB/

Here is the CSS:

```
.secondDiv {
    display: table;
}
.repeatingDiv {
    display: table-cell;
}
```